# Failed to fetch ec2 uri http://169.254.169.254/

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet

I have this simple puppet manifest

```
class javaora(include ::archive) {
  group { 'serviceusrgroup':
    name   => 'serviceusrgroup',
    ensure => 'present',
  }

  user { 'jersey':
    name    => 'jersey',
    home    => '/home/jersey',
    gid     => 'serviceusrgroup',
    comment => 'User to Run servers',
  }

  file { ['/usrdata/archive', '/usrdata/apps/java']: ensure => 'directory' }

  archive { "/usrdata/archive/${tomcat::jreversion}":
    ensure       => present,
    extract      => true,
    extract_path => '/usrdata/apps/java',
    source       => $tomcat::jredownload,
    creates      => "/usrdata/apps/java/${tomcat::jdkversion}"
  }
```

I am getting error `Failed to fetch ec2 uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/:403 Forbidden`

It also gives me error `at line 2 : Syntax error near include ; expected ")"`

Comment: This doesn't mention the URL, so the error must be in some other part of the manifest. Please [reduce the manifest to the absolute minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and fix any syntax errors, then we'll have a chance at debugging it.

Comment: The syntax error is because you have your include listed in the class parameter arguments and that is not allowed. You need to put it with the rest of the class resources.

Comment: @MattSchuchard : inside { } ?

Comment: Yes, inside the class brackets.

Comment: Okay! Syntax error solved. But I am still getting the `Failed to fetch ec2 uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/:403 Forbidden`

Comment: @l0b0 : I am not used this uri anywhere in my manifest! I have no idea where it is coming from. The variable `jredownload` is path of local repository where jre is saved. `jreversion` and `jdkversion` are just versions of jdk.

Comment: How are you running puppet then? Have you tried using `--graph` to see the dependency graph? I don't think vanilla Puppet would do anything as crazy as fetching AWS-specific data without including some AWS code.